# Is $U_2 \oplus U_1$ a normal subgroup of $U_3?$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Here $U_1$,$U_2$ and $U_3$ are unitary groups. I am interested in the generalization of this question to :

Is $U_k$ $\oplus$ $U_{(n-k)}$ a normal subgroup of $U_n$?

where $0< k < n$.

The motivation is to look at the quotient group,
$$G = U_n/(U_k\oplus U_{(n-k)})$$
once it is established that the above statement holds true.

Any leads will be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is there an easy way to see this?
Also, an independent question - Is there a characterization for all the matrices in $U_n$, which are not of the form $U_k \oplus U_{(n-k)}$?